# Issue building libtensorflow_cc.so for arm64-v8a

Tags: android, c++, linux, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to build libtensorflow_cc.so for android for arm64-v8a architecture using bazel

**Requirement**

I am trying to build 'libtensorflow_cc.so' for android for arm64-v8a architecture.
I needed it to create and train a model file in Android NDK through C++ at runtime.
I was able do so on Desktop using C++ with the help of 'libtensorflow_cc.so' generated by

> bazel build -c opt //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so

, but wanted to integrate with Android NDK now and train on mobile.

I tried with 'libtensorflow.so' , but i get below error

> tensorflow_jni.cc:359 Non-OK-status: session->Create (graph_def)
>   status: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op
>   'SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' with these attrs. Registered
>   devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
>                                                                  [[Node: SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
>   = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlabels=DT_INT64](add, Cast)]]

I also tried with
 'libtensorflow_inference.so' but I get many undefined reference errors
 like below

> In function tensorflow::TensorShapeRep::~TensorShapeRep()':
>   /home/ashok/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-arm64-v8a-dnn/facerecognitionlibrary/jni-build/jni/include/include1/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.h:492:
>   undefined reference
>   totensorflow::TensorShapeRep::DestructorOutOfLine()'
>   ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/tensorflow_cc1/tensorflowTrian_jni.o:
>   In function std::pair::~pair()':
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/android-ndk-r12b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_pair.h:96:
>   undefined reference totensorflow::Tensor::~Tensor()'
>   ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/tensorflow_cc1/tensorflowTrian_jni.o:
>   In function std::string* tensorflow::internal::MakeCheckOpString(long const&, int const&, char const*)':
>   /home/ashok/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-arm64-v8a-dnn/facerecognitionlibrary/jni-build/jni/include/include1/tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h:184:
>   undefined reference
>   totensorflow::internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char
>   const*)'

Hence building libtensorflow_cc.so for arm64-v8a using below code

**Code**

> bazel build -c opt //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
>   --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --cpu=arm64-v8a

**Logs**

> WARNING: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in
>   srcs attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:avgpooling_op.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:bounds_check.h' directly. You should either
>   move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
>   WARNING: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in
>   srcs attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:cwise_ops.h' directly. You should either
>   move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
>   WARNING: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in
>   srcs attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:cwise_ops_common.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:cwise_ops_gradients.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_activations.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_attention.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_backward_cuboid_convolutions.h'
>   directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on
>   an appropriate rule there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_backward_spatial_convolutions.h'
>   directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on
>   an appropriate rule there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_cuboid_convolution.h' directly. You
>   should either move the file to this package or depend on an
>   appropriate rule there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_pooling.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_softmax.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_spatial_convolutions.h' directly. You
>   should either move the file to this package or depend on an
>   appropriate rule there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:eigen_volume_patch.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:fifo_queue.h' directly. You should either
>   move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
>   WARNING: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in
>   srcs attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:maxpooling_op.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:ops_util.cc' directly. You should either
>   move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
>   WARNING: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in
>   srcs attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:ops_util.h' directly. You should either
>   move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
>   WARNING: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in
>   srcs attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:padding_fifo_queue.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:pooling_ops_common.cc' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:pooling_ops_common.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:queue_base.h' directly. You should either
>   move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
>   WARNING: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in
>   srcs attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:queue_op.h' directly. You should either
>   move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
>   WARNING: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in
>   srcs attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/kernels:typed_queue.h' directly. You should either
>   move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
>   WARNING: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in
>   srcs attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/util/ctc:ctc_beam_entry.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/util/ctc:ctc_beam_scorer.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/util/ctc:ctc_beam_search.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/util/ctc:ctc_decoder.h' directly. You should either
>   move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
>   WARNING: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in
>   srcs attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/util/ctc:ctc_loss_util.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/util/tensor_bundle:naming.cc' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/util/tensor_bundle:naming.h' directly. You should
>   either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule
>   there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/util/tensor_bundle:tensor_bundle.cc' directly. You
>   should either move the file to this package or depend on an
>   appropriate rule there WARNING:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:952:12: in srcs
>   attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import
>   '//tensorflow/core/util/tensor_bundle:tensor_bundle.h' directly. You
>   should either move the file to this package or depend on an
>   appropriate rule there ERROR:
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/c/eager/BUILD:11:1: in deps
>   attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/c/eager:c_api: target
>   '//tensorflow/c/eager:c_api_internal' does not exist. Since this rule
>   was created by the macro 'tf_cuda_library', the error might have been
>   caused by the macro implementation in
>   /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:667:12 ERROR:
>   Analysis of target '//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so' failed; build
>   aborted INFO: Elapsed time: 0.252s FAILED: Build did NOT complete
>   successfully (0 packages loaded)

Please help resolve the issues

Comment: How did you fix that issue? The answer below doesn't seem to address the warning `You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there`

Comment: To fix the initial "No OpKernel" error you need to add the ops you use to the android_extended_ops_group1 target in tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L4568   . The library got built even though there were warnings

Comment: Do you know how to resolve this error `this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_image_op.cc':                                                                                                                    './tensorflow/core/lib/jpeg/jpeg_mem.h'                       './tensorflow/core/platform/jpeg.h'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the initial "No OpKernel" error you need to add the ops you use to the android_extended_ops_group1 target in tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD#L4568

You can find some more details about why this is needed in the TF for Mobile ebook, here:
http://www.oreilly.com/data/free/building-mobile-applications-with-tensorflow.csp

Comment: What is that warning, `You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there` caused by?